# Captcha Image works in localhost but not on webserver

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, captcha

I am trying to use a custom Text Captcha inside a UpdatePanel. It works fine on localhost, but when I deploy it to the webserver it is not displaying. I am using VS 2010 - vb.net for code and asp.net 4.0 and IIS 6.0 is on the webserver. Here is my code:

```
   Private Function GenerateRandomCode() As String 

  'Generate a random number for the CAPTCHA image 
    Dim s As String = "" 
    For i As Integer = 0 To 5 
        s = s + Me.rand.Next(10).ToString() 
    Next 
    Return s 

End Function 

Public Sub SetCaptcha() 
    'Create a new captcha image 
    Me.Session("CaptchaImageText") = GenerateRandomCode() 
    'append current date to image url to assure loading of new image 
    Me.lblResult.ImageUrl = "GetImage.aspx?" + DateTime.Now.ToString() 
End Sub 


Partial Class GetImage 
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page 
Private Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load 

    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache) 
    'Create a CAPTCHA image using the text stored in the Session object. 
    Dim ci As New CaptchaImage.CaptchaImage(Me.Session("CaptchaImageText"), 200, 50, "Century Schoolbook") 

    Me.Response.Clear() 
    Me.Response.ContentType = "image/png" 

    ci.Image.Save(Me.Response.OutputStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg) 

    ci.Dispose() 
End Sub 

End Class

enter code here
```

Comment: Check the URL the captcha is requesting both on localhost and after publish. It may be that one of them contains the virtual directory name inside, and another doesn't.

Comment: I would add Me.Response.Flush and then Me.Response.End after ci.Dispose.

Comment: Tengiz - actually the published one does:

http://localhost:3368/GetImage.aspx?6/5/2013 10:07:24 AM
http://mysiteexample.org/MessageBoard/GetImage.aspx?6/5/2013 10:08:29 AM

Sorry for the delayed response I did not get a notification email of a post